# Behavior subject subscribed multiple times on single next - Angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a behavior subject in header component it will emit when the user login and have the access to show documents.

That behavior subject is subscribed in another component and  document will be open up.

Problem is behavior subject variable is emitted only one time in header but subscribed multiple times.

The count will increase one by one after every login

I can't unsubscribe that behavior subject in the doc component any solution for this .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rxjs , inside a pipe you should use take(1), thats mean that the first time you emit it will close the event.
You shouls use it like that:

```
.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(()=>{})
```

Comment: import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';